# python multiprocess socket.error when cleaning up

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I would like to process data using pythons multiprocess. As I understand it all processes are separate and do not share data by default. My processes do complex processing. If I stop it by a KeyboardInterrupt then the processes need to clean up properly for which they need the processed data. Here is my problem because the processes already finished at the point at which I want to clean up. So the processed data is lost.

I tried to copy the processed results to the main thread. But no success.

```py
class do_stuff(object):

    def start_processes(self):
        manager = Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        procs = []
        try:
            for rank in range(1):
                p = Process(target=Solver._run,
                            args=(self, arguments, return_dict))
                p.daemon = True
                p.start()
                procs.append(p)
            for p in procs:
                p.join()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        finally:
            #copy properties from return_dict to self
            for key in return_dict.keys():
                setattr(self, key, return_dict[key])   # socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
            for p in procs:
                p.clean_up()
    def _run(self, arguments, return_dict):
        self.run(arguments)

        #copy properties from self to return_dict
        for key in vars(self):
            v = getattr(self, key)
            if not callable(v):
                return_dict[key] = v

    def clean_up(self):
        #use some of the processed data which now should be in 'self'


do_stuff().start_processes()
```

This code is a fast hack. I am aware that the copying for more than 1 worker Processes will have weird results.

For the code above I get the message: socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Please post the full code. By default multiprocessing won't allocate any shared memory, so there won't be any data sent back to main process.

Comment: How can I sent back data in case of KeyboardInterrupt Exception?